# How to inject a script in html pages without touching the application code in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, instrumentation, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to inject some Javascript code (which tracks total requests made from browser) in html responses in my ASP.NET Core application. I know that we can use middleware to manipulate the responses in ASP.NET Core. But I believe it requires changes in application code and redeployment. I want to do it without touching/modifying the application code, so that I can use it multiple applications. How can I achieve that?

Comment: There is no such way to add the JavaScript in the asp.net application without modifying code. and this is also not secure as mentioned in this official documnet:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-7.0. if you really want to use then you could try iis custom module if the site is hosted on the iis server, reverse proxy